# Why is '*' an invalid Request.Path character?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I could not search/find answer for this question. Please help me understand.

Background:
I'm working on adding a new rest-api, which will take version (1.0.1) as an input in string format and return resource accordingly.
I was wondering 1.* is also a valid input version value, where user is saying I'm not aware of latest version in 1.*, fine with any latest minor/patch version as long as major version is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Actually * should be safe character in URL .... look in below link

https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Try encoding it ..

Either replace "*" with "%2A" or use URL encoding utility function

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Encoding doesn't help either. I get below exception:
<br>
[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (*).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9903832
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53